# Javascript ellipsis truncates text incorrectly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have JavaScript code that creates the "read more" effect on a text.The code affects the text incorrectly, breaking it and leaving a single letter or two, and when you click read more, it adds a line-break (which it is not supposed to).

I can't find why or how to avoid this.

[image: http://i61.tinypic.com/9kc9lj.png]

- Words shouldn't be cut.
- Text should be in the same line.

This is the code that creates the "read more" effect :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  $('.slides-large').bxSlider({
    mode : 'fade',
    auto : true
  });

  jQuery('div.menu-main-menu-container').meanmenu();

  var showChar = 297;
  var ellipsestext = "...";
  var moretext = "Read more";
  var lesstext = "Show less";
  $('ul.people li.directors p, .advisory-boards ul.people li p').each(function() {
    var content = $(this).html();

    if (content.length > showChar) {
      var c = content.substr(0, showChar);
      var h = content.substr(showChar - 0, content.length - showChar);

      var html = c + '<span class="moreellipses">' + ellipsestext + '&nbsp;</span><span class="morecontent"><span>' + h + '</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="" class="morelink">' + moretext + '</a></span>';

      $(this).html(html);
    }

  });
  $(".morecontent > span").hide();
  $(".morelink").click(function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass("less")) {
      $(this).removeClass("less");
      $(this).html(moretext);
    } else {
      $(this).addClass("less");
      $(this).html(lesstext);
    }
    $(this).parent().prev().toggle();
    $(this).prev().toggle();
    return false;
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to break at a word, I would recommend looking into the [`lastIndexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/lastIndexOf) method on strings. You can use it to find an index that is right after a word (or punctuation) rather than in the middle of a word:

```
// Find the index of the first space before the cut-off point.
var showCharSpace = content.lastIndexOf(' ', showChar);
// Handle the corner case of there not being any spaces.
if (showCharSpace == -1) showCharSpace = showChar;

var c = content.substr(0, showCharSpace);
// and so on...
```

As for your line break issue that looks more like a CSS problem to me. The elements are `<span>` elements which by default are inline. If they break that might be because they have been changed to have `display: block;` which will make them render as independent blocks rather than inline text. Try changing the display of the `<span>` elements.

Comment: is possible to paste the code you provide to replace how my code is working? or I have to re-make all? thanks , Im really not very experienced in JS.